# Stop and return output buffering at the same time

Tags: php, buffer

Once I have started output buffering with `ob_start()`, I would like, in one command, to stop the output buffering and get its content (without sending it to the output). [I reviewed the available functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php), and my understanding of each function is as follows:

```
                 clear  return  send    stop
ob_clean          x         
ob_end_clean      x                      x
ob_end_flush                      x      x
ob_flush                          x 
ob_get_clean      x        x             x  // should be called ob_get_end_clean
ob_get_contents            x        
ob_get_flush               x      x
```

As far as I can see, there isn't a function which returns the output after stopping the buffering, so when I want to capture the output of a function I have to do it in 3 steps:

```
$output = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
return $output;
```

**Am I missing something or is there a command to stop and return the output buffer in one go?**

Comment: You are missing something, yes. [`ob_get_clean`](http://php.net/ob_get_clean) stops , not only clears, buffering.

Comment: True (and I think it should have been called `ob_get_end_clean`)

Comment: or `ob_get_contents_end_clean()` ?  Which would be in short `ob_get_clean` then. Maybe that helps to memorize the function name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To say it with [the manual](http://php.net/ob_get_clean):

> **`ob_get_clean()`** essentially executes both `ob_get_contents()` and `ob_end_clean()`.

(highlight by me). Comparing with your code:

```
$output = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
```

Your listing must have missed something.

Comment: Take care when you have multiple levels of output buffering, calling the function once might not be enough.

Answer (score 1):

This should be the one, it even mentions it in the description :)

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-clean.php